# Android Custom View with specific shape

Tags: android, layout, view, shapes

Can I create a custom view with this specific shape? I would like to create my own component and then use it like in the picture, aligning them in a linearlayout for example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can create Custom Layout and then Design it in Linear Layout. I would Suggest you to go through Layout Inflator Topic in Android Studio Documentation.

Comment: My concern is first how to create this specific shape. The linearlayout part come after.

Comment: I think it will hep you https://www.raywenderlich.com/9556022-drawing-custom-shapes-in-android